# javascript jquery script conflicts

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have this list of js files, using jquery and ajax in my header.php on my website:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.spritely.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.backgroundPosition.js"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/slot.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>'
```

But the two last scripts (slot,js and script) dont work at same time, if I delete one of them or switch them it works, but only one of them (the 1st declared). The problem of the scripts is the buttons stop working (click event).
I'm using document.ready, bind and on click events, on both scripts.
If a put a jQuery.noConflict on the slot.js, this script will always work but script.js not, no matter the order of js in the header.php

Any sujestion ? thx for your help!

P.S: I think the problem is bcs jquery, since if i chg the order of the first four js files nothing works.

Comment: Check the console to see the exact error given. This should give you a starting point to find what the conflict is.

Comment: You're including jQuery twice.

Comment: Why are you loading two versions of jQuery?

Comment: get rid of one of the jquery's. include latest jquery

Comment: jQuery must always be included first, before any script that uses jQuery is included. If you need to two jQuery version use noConflict() to separate them.

Comment: Error of console: Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function on script.js, if I switch the last 2 js script it give same error

Answer (score 0):

jquery.min.js is a minified version of jquery-1-9-1.js so you only need to call one of them and make sure you call it before any of the other scripts.

Comment: thx for the tip, but if I remove a single jquery script nothing works :s

Comment: Try changing the `$` on the scripts you have written to `jQuery`, this should avoid conflicts with other scripts.

Comment: still same, i tried...jQuery(document).ready(function..., ....jQuery(function(...., jQuery.noConflict();... like here http://www.surfingsuccess.com/jquery/document-ready.html#.U15jcvldVe9

Comment: If you enter all of your coding into a jsfiddle.net fiddle I'll take a closer look at the workings.